# What metadata can be stored in a .dv file?

Tags: video, file-formats

I'd just like to know what information I can expect to extract from a dv file. A lot of file formats have provisions for embedded metadata of all sorts, so my question is what if any data could a .dv file have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can check http://www.videohelp.com/tools/DV_Datecode and http://www.avpreserve.com/dvanalyzer/dv-metadata/
the rest is on google :)

i was using an automated software developed in house to extract the info, later on we moved to FinalCutServer so we get to manage everything in there...

edit: this link could help you. http://premierepro.wikia.com/wiki/DVMP

Comment: Thanks. Just waht I needed, but was unable to come up with using Google.